# Cartalyst Sentinel check() always returns false in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5, cartalyst-sentinel

I use Cartalyst Sentinel to authenticate user

```
$status=Sentinel::authenticate($credentials);
```

the above code is in the login function in `UserController`. In the login function I can see that the `Sentinel::check()` returns some data. However, after login and redirecting the another page in the `AccountController`, the `Sentinel::check()` always returns false despite the user has logged in and not yet trigged the logout button.

Anyone knows how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to verify that you are setting the user to remember.

`Sentinel::authenticateAndRemember($credentials)`

Just authenticating doesn't set the user in the session.  If that doesn't fix your problem you should verify the Facade you're using.  Sentinel comes packaged with two facades, both a Laravel and Native facade.  If you're using Laravel and call the Native Facade you will get a false return.  The inverse does the same.

Hope that helps.